# Can I have event listeners stored as properties of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to "store" the event listener of a DOM Element to a "unique" property of it, so that I could later removed it. Some like this:

```
const listener = e => {};

myElement.addEventListener("keyup", listener);
myElement.keyUPListener = listener;

// ...later, where I don't have access to 'listener'
myElement.removeEventListener("keyup", myElement.keyUPListener)
```

Is this a bad/good practice?

Comment: Sure, that's an option, though having to do something like that is a bit of a code smell - consider refactoring instead so that you *do* have access to `listener` when you need to remove it (pass a `Map` around, maybe)

Comment: oh, yeah, a Map would be much more helpful here! thanks for the idea :)